# angular 2 Observable complete not called

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables

I am playing around with hero app fro angular 2 tutorial and right now i have this Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Hero } from "./hero";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { HeroService } from "./hero.service";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";


@Component({
    selector: 'hero-search',
    templateUrl: 'app/hero-search.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/hero-search.component.css'],
})
export class HeroSearchComponent implements OnInit{
    heroes: Hero[];
    isLoading: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
    error: any;
    private searchNameStream = new Subject<string>();

    constructor(
        private heroService: HeroService,
        private router: Router
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.searchNameStream
            .debounceTime(400)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .switchMap(name => {
                this.isLoading.next(true);
                return this.heroService.getHeroesByName(name)
            })
            .subscribe(
                heroes => this.heroes = heroes,
                error => this.error = error,
                () => {
                    console.log('completed');
                    this.isLoading.next(false);
                })
    }

    // Push a search term into the observable stream.
    search(Name: string): void {
        this.searchNameStream.next(Name)
    }

    gotoDetail(hero: Hero): void {
        let link = ['/detail', hero.id];
        this.router.navigate(link);
    }

}
```

The problem is that, if i understand it correctly, subscribe takes three callback parameters `.subscribe(success, failure, complete);`. But in my case the complete part is never executed. I guess it has something to do with how switchMap works. Am i right?

Comment: The searchNameStream never completes, so the observable obtained from switchMap never completes either.

Comment: isn`t it observable returned by this.heroService.getHeroesByName(name) ?

Comment: No. Every time an event is emitted by the searchNameStream, `heroService.getHeroesByName()` is called and all the events emitted by this "inner" observable are reemitted by the "outer" observable, until a new event is emitted by the searchNameStream, and this process repeats. You subscribed to the outer observable, which will only complete when the searchNameStream completes.

Comment: Ok. I understand it now. So is there a way to get complete event of inner observable, or should i take another approach?

Comment: Replace `return this.heroService.getHeroesByName(name)` by `return this.heroService.getHeroesByName(name).finally(() => { this.isLoading.next(false); })`

Comment: @JBNizet why don't you provide a formal SO answer?

Comment: Now i am getting error during compilation to js `Property 'length' is missing in type '{}'.` and `TypeError: _this.heroService.getHeroesByName(...).finally is not a function` in browser console.

Comment: You need to import the operator: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally';import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally';`

Comment: still. Same error.
`app/hero-search.component.ts(33,34): error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Hero[]'.
app/hero-search.component.ts(33,34): error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Hero[]'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type '{}'`

Comment: Use this: `.finally<Hero[]>(...`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `searchNameStream` never completes, so the observable obtained from `switchMap` never completes either.

Every time an event is emitted by the `searchNameStream`, `heroService.getHeroesByName()` is called and all the events emitted by this "inner" observable are reemitted by the "outer" observable, until a new event is emitted by the `searchNameStream`, and this process repeats. You subscribed to the outer observable, which will only complete when the `searchNameStream` completes.